# Segfault from cv::VideoCapture::grab() after many cv::VideoCapture() constructions

Tags: opencv

I get segfault from cv::VideoCapture::grab() (actually, >> operator) in the following code.

The error occurs after more than 100 loops.

```
while(1) {
    boost::timer te;

    // create VideoCapture instance
    cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
    if(!cap.isOpened()) { /* shutdown code */ }
    cv::Mat frame;
    std::vector<uchar> buf;

    // get the latest frame from camera
    cap >> frame;

    // save frame as png image
    cv::imencode(".png", frame, buf);
    std::string data(buf.begin(), buf.end());
    my.saveImage(data);

    // release capture device
    cap.release();

    // wait 1 second
    boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io, boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1000.0 - te.elapsed() * 1000));
    t.wait();
}
```

Error from gdb is

```
(gdb) where
#0  0xb7dcfe75 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3
#1  0xb7dcff03 in CvCaptureCAM_V4L_CPP::grabFrame() () from /usr/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3
#2  0xb7dbd783 in cvGrabFrame () from /usr/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3
#3  0xb7dbd7bf in cv::VideoCapture::grab() () from /usr/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3
#4  0xb7dbd562 in cv::VideoCapture::operator>>(cv::Mat&) () from /usr/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3
#5  0x0804a464 in main (argv=3, argc=0xbfffea44) at main.cpp:31
```

Error from valgrind is

```
==28670== Invalid write of size 4
==28670==    at 0x4242E75: ??? (in /usr/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1)
==28670==    by 0x4242F02: CvCaptureCAM_V4L_CPP::grabFrame() (in /usr/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1)
==28670==    by 0x46A14D2: (below main) (libc-start.c:226)
==28670==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==28670==
==28670==
==28670== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==28670==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==28670==    at 0x4242E75: ??? (in /usr/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1)
==28670==    by 0x4242F02: CvCaptureCAM_V4L_CPP::grabFrame() (in /usr/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3.1)
==28670==    by 0x46A14D2: (below main) (libc-start.c:226)
==28670==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==28670==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==28670==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==28670==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==28670==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
```

I have two questions.

- What is the best practice to get snapshot periodically?
- How can I avoid this error?

Additional information:

- environment: Ubuntu 12.04, OpenCV 2.3.1-7 from apt, V4L2
- My device did not accept FPS setter.
- The full code is https://github.com/tomykaira/accamlator/blob/master/client/linux/main.cpp

Comment: any special reason to create a new capture for each frame ?

Comment: With `grab()`, the retrieved frame is not up to date.  It seems to need grab all frames.

Answer (score 0):

first, don't create a new capture every time. it's not nessecary, and a very expensive operation.

```
// create VideoCapture instance
cv::VideoCapture cap(0);

while(cap.isOpened()) 
{
    boost::timer te;

    cv::Mat frame;
    std::vector<uchar> buf;

    // get the latest frame from camera
    cap >> frame;

    if ( ! frame.empty() )  // check it, please
    {
        // save frame as png image
        cv::imencode(".png", frame, buf);
        std::string data(buf.begin(), buf.end());
        my.saveImage(data);
    }

    // wait 1 second
    boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io, boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1000.0 - te.elapsed() * 1000));
    t.wait();
}
//cap.release(); // can care for itself
```

then, encoding an image into a std::string might lead to a lot of unexpected file-truncations (no idea, what my.saveImage() is doing, but zeros are total legit in an image, but not in a string, right ?)

why not just use imwrite() here ?

last but not least, 2.3.1 is *very* old, better update to 2.4.7

Comment: As far as I've tested, combination of `grab()` (which is called in `>>` operator) and `t.wait()` misbehaves.
The image captured is of several seconds ago.
I suspect the reason is that the image is taken from the first frame of buffer.
I need a method to grab the capture the last frame.

`saveImage()` stores the image into MySQL DB as a BLOB.

I'll try update.